# PHP Array Tree in Loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, tree

I need generate Array Tree like:

```
 Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
     [parent] => 1 
         Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname
         Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname 
   )
 ) 
  Array ( 
  [1] => Array ( 
        [parent] => 1 
            Array( [name] =>name 
                   [lastname] => lastname
            Array( [name] =>name 
                   [lastname] => lastname
    )
  )
```

My code is:

```
 foreach($something as $value)
 {
      $array[] = Array('parent' => $value);
      foreach($somethingelse as $valueelse)
      {
         $array[] = Array('name' => $valueelse, 'lastname' => $valueelse2);
      }

 }
```

Output with this code is:

```
 Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
     [parent] => 1 
  [1] => Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname )
  [2] => Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname )
 ) 
 Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
     [parent] => 1 
  [1] => Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname )
  [2] => Array( [name] =>name 
                [lastname] => lastname )
   )
```

I am building tree for email output and sometimes I got null array in children so my goal is something like:

parent
children
children
parent
children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pushing all the values to the same array

when you write `array[] = value` it will add the **new value at the end of the array**.

as per your requirement you have to create subarray first and then add the new array into parent array some thing like this

```
foreach($something as $value)
 {
      $subArray = Array('parent' => $value);
      foreach($somethingelse as $valueelse)
      {
         $subArray[] = Array('name' => $valueelse, 'lastname' => $valueelse2);
      }

      // your subarray will be array(parent=>1,array('name'=>value....)) and 
      //we dd this sub array into main array.
      $array[] = $subArray;

 }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks.